# Knit child documents in standalone mode

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

According to https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/child/ it is possible to knit child documents on their own by using set_parent() in a chunk.

I tried that:

```
knitr::set_parent("<PATH TO MAIN FILE>")
```

But that does not seem to work. Knitting the child does not take information in the YAML section of the parent into account. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Currently this function only works for Rnw documents. You may file a feature request to https://github.com/yihui/knitr for the support for Rmd documents. Thanks!

Comment: just did! thank you very much for your excellent work on rmarkdown (and related packages), it is such a valuable tool to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that you can use to input the YAML frontmatter of an arbitrary Rmd file into another Rmd file:

```r
input_yaml = function(file) {
  lines = xfun::read_utf8(file)
  meta = rmarkdown:::partition_yaml_front_matter(lines)$front_matter
  knitr::asis_output(paste(meta, collapse = '\n'))
}
```

If you don't prefer `:::`, you could also use:

```r
input_yaml = function(file) {
  meta = rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(file)
  meta = c('---', yaml::as.yaml(meta), '---')
  knitr::asis_output(paste(meta, collapse = '\n'))
}
```

Then in the child document, you may do this:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
input_yaml('parent.Rmd')
```

This is a child document without YAML.
````

Comment: looks like a very good workaround, but this is not working for me, after putting in the function my document still knits as a standard html document

Comment: @maxpe Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? I'm unable to offer help only by knowing something is "not working". Thanks!

Comment: sorry that was unclear from my side, i create as parent the standard rmd document in rstudio, set pdf_document as output, if i take your example child document above (with the function defined) and link it to the parent, it still knits an html document not a pdf

Comment: btw my other question is also yaml related, could that be a problem from the setup on my side? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987994/knit-with-custom-parameters

Comment: @maxpe I see. That will be hard. I mean it is hard to inform **rmarkdown** or the RStudio IDE to use the output format of the parent document. You have to explicitly call `rmarkdown::render('child.Rmd', output_format = 'pdf_document')`.